# Struts2 related setup/first application errors

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, struts2

I am a newbie in struts2 programming and web applications. I am learning and following the hello world project from struts2 website. It seems to be straight forward, but I ran into a lot of problem running the project.
Here is the link to the material that I am using:http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/hello-world-using-struts2.html
I am also getting jars from external repository through maven

Here are the errors that I got:

> 1.[main] ERROR DomHelper:363 - The content of element type "package" must match
>   "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-allowed-methods?,global-exception-mappings?,action*)".
>   at (null:18:12) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element
>   type "package" must match
>   "(result-types?,interceptors?,default-interceptor-ref?,default-action-ref?,default-class-ref?,global-results?,global-allowed-methods?,global-exception-mappings?,action*)".
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_101]    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
>   [?:1.8.0_101]

............

> 2.[main] ERROR Dispatcher:498 - Dispatcher initialization failed com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load
>   configuration.    at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
>   ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
>   ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445) ~[struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
>   [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]  at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
>   [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]  at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
>   [struts2-core-2.5.10.1.jar:2.5.10.1]

............
Then the console tells me that they are unable to load configuration.

Here is my pom file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.certus</groupId>
<artifactId>strutstest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>strutstest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>20030203.000550</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker-gae</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.0-CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.32</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <finalName>basic-struts</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/${build.finalName}</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my struts file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="strutstest" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="index">
        <result>/index.jsp</result>
    </action>、

    <action name="hey" class="com.certus.strutstest.Action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/heyyy.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I followed the tutorial step by step, but I have no idea what could go wrong. Please help if you have seen these errors. Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual `struts.xml`

Comment: Look `</action>、`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Hey thanks for pointing it out to me. I can't believe I missed that.